# Laravel - Unable to filter database using 'Where' Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I thought this would be simple to solve, but I have not been able to figure it out. I am trying to filter my database with a `where()` statement.

The Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) states this:

```
DB::table('satellites')->where('satname', 'falcon')->get();
```

I tried the query as stated in the documentation, but that did not work unfortunately.

I am trying to filter that database with the word `falcon` in the column `satname` in my database called `satellites`.

I also tried: `->where('satname', '=', 'falcon')`.

I think that I am just doing a simple mistake and forgetting something!

Comment: Any error? I think you forgot to use this "use DB" on top of the page.

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: @BikashP I do have `use DB` in my controller.

Comment: @D.777KLM Any error ?

Comment: There is no error in the `laravel.log` file.

Comment: If you do normal select all do you get properly output?

Comment: @Wolen Yes, I get all the whole database when I don't include the 'where' statement.

Comment: @D.777KLM Please display result set without include where condition

Comment: If you do `SELECT * FROM satellites WHERE satname = 'falcon';` in your database, do you get results? If you have access to the server, you can also try turning the mysql log on with `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'on';`, run the query in laravel, then set the general_log back to off. You can then find the general log (`show variables like 'general%'`) and check to see what is actually being generated.

Comment: Does a RawQuery also not work?
`DB::table('satellites')->whereRaw('satname = "falcon"')->get()`

if not can you dump your sql like so: 
`DB::table('satellites')->where('satname', 'falcon')->toSql()`

Comment: Managed to figure out the problem - it works if I search for the specific query I want. `falcon` does not work, but `FALCON 9` works.

Comment: @D.777KLM Its common sense man

Comment: Ah. Then you're looking for `LIKE` instead of `=`, since it's not an exact search. `->where('satname', 'LIKE', '%falcon%')` (falcon anywhere in the string) or `->where('satname', 'LIKE', 'falcon%')` (starts with falcon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "filter," and by looking at the comments it seems this means not exact searching, meaning not *exactly* 'falcon' but things containing falcon. What you're looking for is the LIKE operator.

```
DB::table('satellites')
    ->whereRaw("satname LIKE 'falcon%'")
    ->get();
```

This would return anything where satname starts with falcon: falcon 1, falcon 9, falcon 318929, etc.

To get everything containing falcon, use "satname LIKE '%falcon%'". This would include things like: falcon 9, test falcon, test falcon 82, etc.

Comment: I had looked through the comments before typing my post and hadn't seen the commented solution. After posting it I see @aynber had commented the solution already. Very sorry!